# How to receive source URL of clipboard copied data with JS or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As in OneNote, whatever I will copy in OneNote pages, it will copy my URL link from where I copied this data too. As it was [described](https://www.quora.com/How-does-OneNote-know-the-URL-from-which-you-have-copied-something), the OneNote can receive link thanks to browser that will copy it to its HTML format.

Therefore, I suppose, it is possible to get it with JS or jQuery. Not during copy event, just get it from clipboard whenever after copy operation occured.

This will just get data from clipboard, but not the URL source data:

```js
        $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#main").on("paste",function(event){
              event.preventDefault();
              var clipboarddata =  window.event.clipboardData.getData('text');    
              console.log("paste value" + clipboarddata);
              $('#pasteData').text(clipboarddata);
              console.log(window.event);
              console.log(window.event.clipboardData);
            });
            
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <input type="text" id="main" name="first_name" value="" maxlength="100" />
      <div>paste value :  <span id="pasteData"><span></div>
```

Could you please show an code example how to get URL source of copied data?

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is not possible in a web browser context. It may be possible in a Node.js context.

Comment: Uf, ok then... but I have Node.js application ... I can use clipboard-npm, but it is possible to receive the URL from where data was copied - from outer scope of domain of my Node.js client web app? For example, I will copy text from Google Translator, and then I will navigate to my web app server page. Am I possible there to receive URL of google source or not? If yes, how please... I will accept answer for node.js solution too

Comment: Would need to do this in a browser extension

Comment: Yes I saw browser extension solutions, but I cannot force my customers one by one to use browser plugin(and for every kind of browser other) in order to work correctly with my webapp... but on the other hand, I don't see any other way here...after hitting CTRL+C in the browser, the OS system will copy to clipboard selected data with url link to client side computer from HTML format, where this URL later, browsers are not able to receive due to event functions limitation of JS, jQuery...

Comment: Any solutions in 2020?